# "! LaTeX Error: File `umsb.fd' not found." although the file is present

Tags: pdftex, texlive, amsfonts

**Solved**: it was a bug in the `import` texlive package.

---

I've just got to reinstall my tex-live install and after that I've got the following problem during compilation using a dissertation template:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
chapter 1.

! LaTeX Error: File `umsb.fd' not found.
```

I do not understand it, since the file is there:

```
zoltan@aprosag ~/Dropbox/design/My_papers/TUD_dist_vorlage $ head /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
%%
%% This is file `umsb.fd',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
```

I've used LaTeX for a few documents, but I am still very far from being an expert, and my assumption that the files in parenthesis are the ones what the engine try to load at the moment, seems to be incorrect or there has to be some other issues. What does the files in the parenthesis mean? Why is the problem only related to umsb and not to umsa? Since I have not seen any other clue, I do not know how to proceed with the debugging.

Unfortunately the error is related to the used template. I would like to understand the error before I am looking for another template.

I've used pdflatex to compile the document.

Comment: Are you using the import or the subfiles package?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am using the import package.

Comment: It had a bug and this buggy version is in the final texlive 2019. You should either get a newer import from ctan, or install texlive 2020 which has been released today.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer! That was the solution. It has taken me so much time and energy to figure it out!  I am so relieved now! I send you many hugs!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if you add it as answer, I will accept that as the accepted solution.

Comment: I voted to close it as a duplicate - this will make it easier for other to find the relevant answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, it does.